# Trying to get VBA to highlight the changes in an Excel before and after sheet from a database

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code is not highlighting the changes in the Excel after sheet. It highlights data that is the same in both Excel sheets.

```
Sub CompareSheetsIgnoreColumnJ()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, diffCount As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Attempt to set worksheets; catch error if sheet names are incorrect
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Before")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("After")

    diffCount = 0

    ' Loop through each cell in columns A to S in the "Before" sheet
    For Each c In ws1.Range("A1:S" & ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Dim row As Long, col As Long
        row = c.row
        col = c.Column

        ' Check if the cell is within the columns A to S of "After" sheet
        If row <= ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count And col <= 19 Then

            Dim val1, val2
            val1 = c.Value
            val2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Value

            ' Compare values in the two sheets
            If IsNumeric(val1) And IsNumeric(val2) Then
                If Abs(val1 - val2) > 0.000000001 Then
                    ' Highlight differences in red
                    ws2.Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 71, 76)
                    diffCount = diffCount + 1
                End If
            ElseIf val1 <> val2 Then
                ' Highlight non-numeric differences
                ws2.Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 71, 76)
                diffCount = diffCount + 1
            End If
        End If

NextCell:
    Next c

    ' Display the number of differences found
    MsgBox diffCount & " differences found", vbInformation

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub
```

I tried rewriting the VBA code but for some reason it's not working. I'm new to VBA so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Side note: Spreadsheet Compare in Excel can compare two workbooks and identify differences. May or may not be useful here, but just in case you're reinventing functionality that already exists.

Comment: Would I have to save the sheets in different workbooks to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this.

```
Sub CompareSheetsIgnoreColumnJ()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, cll As Range
    Dim arr1, arr2, lr&, lc&, row&, col&, diffCount As Long
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Attempt to set worksheets; catch error if sheet names are incorrect
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Before")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("After")
    lr = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With ws2.UsedRange.Rows
      If lr < .Count Then lr = .Count
    End With
    lc = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    With ws2.UsedRange.Columns
      If lc < .Count Then lc = .Count
    End With
    
    arr1 = ws1.Cells(1).Resize(lr, lc)
    arr2 = ws2.Cells(1).Resize(lr, lc)
    diffCount = 0

    ' Loop through each cell in columns A to S in the "Before" sheet
    For row = 1 To lr
        For col = 1 To lc
            If IsNumeric(arr1(row, col)) And IsNumeric(arr2(row, col)) Then
                If Abs(arr1(row, col) - arr2(row, col)) Then
                    ws2.Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 4999167 'RGB(255, 71, 76)
                    diffCount = diffCount + 1
                End If
            ElseIf arr1(row, col) <> arr2(row, col) Then
                ws2.Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 5046087 'RGB(71, 255, 76)
                diffCount = diffCount + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Display the number of differences found
    MsgBox diffCount & " differences found", vbInformation
    
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub
```